# What is the derivative of: $f(x)=x^{2x^{3x^{4x^{5x^{6x^{7x^{.{^{.^{.}}}}}}}}}}$?

Tags: differential-calculus

I happened to ponder about the differentiation of the following function:
$$f(x)=x^{2x^{3x^{4x^{5x^{6x^{7x^{.{^{.^{.}}}}}}}}}}$$
Now, while I do know how to manipulate power towers to a certain extent, and know the general formula to differentiate $g(x)$ wrt $x$, where $$g(x)=f(x)^{f(x)^{f(x)^{f(x)^{f(x)^{f(x)^{f(x)^{.{^{.^{.}}}}}}}}}}$$ 
I'm still unable to figure out as to how I can adequately manipulate the function to differentiate it within its domain of convergence, if it exists.

**Sub-Q: What is the domain over which the function converges? Does it have only a finite domain (meaning there's no necessity to discuss its derivative)?**

---

General formula (making domanial assumptions for f(x) of course): $$g'(x)=\frac{g^2(x)f'(x)}{f(x)\left[1-g(x)\ln(f(x))\right]}$$

---

**Note**: This has been posted in stackexchange; a look at the (incomplete) answers and their respective comments' sections will give you an insight into what has been looked into so far - [https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1592377/what-is-the-derivative-of-fx-x2x3x4x5x6x7x ]

Comment: I don't wish to seem pedantic, but it isn't obvious to me at a glance what the meaning of this expression is. Perhaps it would be easier to answer the question if you defined $f(x)$ explicitly as the limit of an explicit sequence of functions.

Comment: @Ian Morris: maybe it's a transseries http://arxiv.org/abs/0801.4877 (though, not with "finite exponential height")?

Comment: The convergence of sequences of the form $a_1^{a_2^{a_3^{\cdots a_n}}}$ was investigated by D.F. Barrow in the article ``Infinite Exponentials'' (American Mathematical Monthly **43**, No.3 (1936) p.150-160). Perhaps it is intended that $f(x)$ is to be understood as the limit of a sequence of this type. Barrow's results are sufficient to prove the divergence of the sequence of values $x^{2x^{3x^{\cdots nx}}}$ for $x>e^{1/e}$, but do not seem to provide much clear information in other cases.

Comment: The sequence of values $x^{2x^{3x^{4x^{\cdots nx}}}}$ certainly converges for infinitely many values of $x$, since if $x=1/n$ then all terms in this sequence from the $n^{\mathrm{th}}$ onwards are the same. However it is not clear to me that the set of $x>0$ for which this sequence converges has nonempty interior.

Comment: @IanMorris what is so special about $1/n$? It is so in my wrong interpretation, see my answer below and comments, but how is it in the correct setting?

Comment: @FedorPetrov: I see what you mean, perhaps I am mistaken.

Answer (score 7):

This is not exactly an answer. I try to give a meaning to $f(x)$. 
Not  as a limit.  I will give a formal 
solution as a power series (possibly not converging).

Consider a function of two parameters
$$u(t,x)=(t+1)x^{(t+2)x^{(t+3)x^{(t+4)x^{(t+5)x^{(t+6)x^{(t+7)x^{.{^{.^{.}}}}}}}}}}$$
so that $f(x)=u(0,x)$. Now whatever the meaning we assign to $f(x)$ it appear that 
$u(t,x)$ satisfies the functional equation
$$u(t,x)=(t+1) x^{u(t+1,x)}.$$
So that 
$$\log u(t,x)=\log(t+1)+u(t+1,x)\log x.$$
It is natural to put $u(t,1)=t+1$. So we try an analytic solution
$$u(t,x)=(t+1)\Bigl(1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n(t) (x-1)^n\Bigr)$$
Then 
$$\log\Bigl(1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n(t) (x-1)^n\Bigr)=
(t+2)\Bigl(1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n(t+1) (x-1)^n\Bigr)\log x$$
Expanding 
$$a_1(t)(x-1)+\Bigl(a_2(t)-\frac{1}{2}a_1(t)^2\Bigr)(x-1)^2+
\Bigl(\frac13a_1(t)^3-a_1(t)a_2(t)+a_3(t))(x-1)^3+\cdots =$$
$$=
(t+2)\Bigl(1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n(t+1) (x-1)^n\Bigr)\Bigl((x-1)-\frac{(x-1)^2}{2}+\frac{(x-1)^3}{3}+\cdots\Bigr)$$
Giving equations
$$a_1(t)=t+2$$
$$a_2(t)-\frac{1}{2}a_1(t)^2=-\frac{t+2}{2}+(t+2)a_1(t+1)$$
So 
$$a_2(t)=\frac12(t+2)^2-\frac{t+2}{2}+(t+2)(t+3)=(t+2)\Bigl(\frac{t+2}{2}-\frac12+t+3
\Bigr)=(t+2)\frac{3t+7}{2}. $$
It is easy to show that the equation resulting from equating the coefficients of 
$(x-1)^n$ determine $a_n(t)$ in a unique way, as a polynomial of degree $n$.

With Mathematica we obtain
$$\eqalign{
a_1(t)&=\frac{1}{1!}(2+t)\cr
a_2(t)&=\frac{1}{2!}(14+13t+3t^2)\cr
a_3(t)&=\frac{1}{3!}(234+287t+117t^2+16t^3)\cr
a_4(t)&=\frac{1}{4!}(6792+10014 t+5505 t^2+1348 t^3+125 t^4)\cr
a_5(t)&=\frac{1}{5!}(301980+507614 t+338960 t^2+113200 t^3+19030 t^4+1296 t^5)\cr
a_6(t)&=\frac{1}{6!}(18996384+35272036 t+27073062 t^2+11070440 t^3+2559125 t^4+318834 t^5+16807 t^6)\cr
}$$
Therefore the formal solution is the power series
$$f(x)=1+\frac{2}{1!}(x-1)+\frac{14}{2!}(x-1)^2+\frac{234}{3!}(x-1)^3
+\frac{6792}{4!}(x-1)^4+\frac{301980}{5!}(x-1)^5+\frac{18996384}{6!}(x-1)^6+\cdots
$$
The sequence of coefficients do not appear in the OEIS.
The coefficient of $t^n$ in $a_n(t)$ appear to be $(n+1)^{n-1}$.

I have computed the coefficients of the power series for $f(x)$ for $n\le30$.
It appear that  $\log a_n(t)\le \frac34 n^{3/2}$, (with approximate equality) if this trend continues, the series
will be divergent except for $x=1$.   But Euler summed the 
divergent series $\sum n! x^n$.

Answer (score 6):

Update: it answers a different question.

If $1/(N-1)>x> 1/N$, then $p_N:=(Nx)^{(N+1)x^{\dots}}=\infty$, $p_{N-1}=0$, $p_{N-2}=1$, and so we have a tower of height $N-3$. Thus your function has a jump in points $1/N$ and is smooth between consecutive jumps (values at points of jumps is difficult to define, since $p_N$ for $x=1/N$ is $1^{\infty}$).

How to differentiate a tower? Simply fix all but one appearings of $x$, differentiate with respect to this $x$, and then sum up.

Comment: Why do you write $(Nx)^{(N+1)x^{\dots}}$? The question asks for $N\cdot x^{(N+1)\cdot x^{\dots}}$, doesn't it?

Comment: Hm, then I misunderstood it.

Comment: Indeed; I meant what @SebastianGoette has written.